# My bike's gears won't shift properly or at all

Tags: gears, derailleur, shifting

Firstly, sorry if this has been asked before but I don't know much about bikes. I bought my bike from big w (fairly cheap beginners bike, but I am happy with it). It has two shifters, one on the left (for the front derailleur) I can turn about 90% of the way and the right one (rear derailleur) I can't turn at all. Basically it's stuck in high gear on the rear derailleur and I can't use it or shift it.

I have googled and found this (

) and believe the issue to be specifically with the gears. I tested the derailleur and it works fine.

I am pretty sure the gears are clogged as I haven't used my bike in a couple of months due to rain, and given the video below was hoping for someone to clarify if this is really the issue or it might be something else. If it is, I am assuming some slight disassembly and grease it up/remove any dirt and stuff is the solution.

Video link of the issue: https://youtube.com/shorts/Vp0g6vru4Ps?feature=share

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hey my right gripshift won't turn, need help](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/69126/hey-my-right-gripshift-wont-turn-need-help)

Comment: It is possible that your shift cable(s) got a bit rusty or have gummed up and now have too much friction to slide within the cable housing.  Since you verified that the rear derailleur will still sweep across the rear gears (aka the cassette) I believe it just needs the cables replaced.  That can be done on your own, or your local bike shop can do it.  If you don't have that experience, I would let the bike shop do it.  Don't over twist the rear shifter if it is not moving.  You could break something.  The amount of torque you applied makes me think it will take more than just a cleaning.

Comment: The cables on the whole bike are quite rusty, probably from copious amounts of rain (sometimes being in the rain) and just not being used. I will check with a bike shop as I was trying to figure out how to dismantle the shifter and don't have the tools.

Comment: You probably don't want to dismantle the shifter. They range from difficult to impossible to reassemble. If you're just itching to take something apart, pull the cables out, lube them with a good quality lube, drip some lube into the cable housing, and put it all back together. If that helps, you may consider using the bike as is or replacing those things.

Comment: I just saw your video. Have you tried shifting while riding and pedaling? Shifters are meant to work while the chain is in motion. Trying to shift when not pedaling can easily cause the derailleur to jam, which would limit the shifter movement too.

Comment: I think jimchristie is right - my bike will not let me change further than that when I'm stationary, as the derailleur gets jammed against the next sprocket. Try it while riding.

Comment: I ended up having a friend check it out, and he has basically said it is the cable that needs to be replaced, but he also mentioned since it is a fairly cheap bike and the gears are all rusted, might be worth just getting rid of.

Answer (score 6):

Per the comment thread, the cables are quite rusty. That would surely cause the condition you described and showed in your video.

If the cables are that bad, it really is worth having them replaced by your local bike shop if you don’t have the experience doing cable replacement and derailleur/shifting setup and adjustment. This is a normal repair for a bike shop and you will be amazed at how much better your bike will shift when it is fixed.

And in the future, keep the bike out of the rain when storing it and ensure you dry things off after riding in the rain/wet.

Comment: "And in the future, keep the bike out of the rain when storing it and ensure you dry things off after riding in the rain/wet." Rain/water is really only a problem for cheap bikes. A better bike would have had stainless steel cables.